# Search though accounts on flask-stormpath

Tags: python, flask, stormpath

I have a `flask.ext.stormpath` instance and I would like to fetch all users (filtered with `created_at`)
I have tried several stuff that are not working

```
flask.ext.stormpath.accounts
```

Sorry for the short question but for clarity, I think I need something like this
https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/reference.html#search-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyo,

When you use Flask-Stormpath, you can access the underlying `Application` object by saying:

```
stormpath_manager.application
```

This means you can do stuff like:

```
for account in stormpath_manager.application.accounts:
    print('Email: {}'.format(account.email))
```

Any sort of Python SDK stuff will work here as expected =)